# hasmap return key and value methods give incorrect output

Tags: java, hashmap, set

I want to create methods  which return the amount of same first names and  last names, but when i try to test and compile code i get as output 1 , 1  , and this is not true. because  there is 10 same names and 10 same last names.

```
public class Solution
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        HashMap<String, String> map = createMap();
        System.out.println(getCountTheSameFirstName(map, "test"));
        System.out.println(getCountTheSameLastName(map, "test"));
    }
    public static HashMap<String, String> createMap()
    {
        HashMap<String, String> odin = new HashMap<String, String>();
        odin.put("test","test");
        odin.put("test","test");
        odin.put("test","test");
        odin.put("test","test");
        odin.put("test","test");
        odin.put("test","test");
        odin.put("test","test");
        odin.put("test","test");
        odin.put("test","test");
        odin.put("test","test");

         return odin;
    }

    public static int getCountTheSameFirstName(HashMap<String, String> map, String name)
    {
        int count = 0;
        for(Map.Entry<String, String> lol : map.entrySet()){

        String value = lol.getValue();
            if(name.equals(value)){
                count++;
            }
    }
        return count;
    }

    public static int getCountTheSameLastName(HashMap<String, String> map, String familiy)
    {
        int count=0;
        for (Map.Entry<String,String> pair : map.entrySet())
        {
            String key = pair.getKey();
            if (familiy.equals(key))
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry!! if you are not use duplicate key then you have to have get the output 10 & 0

Your code: Just I have changed the key and got the output 10 & 0:

```
public class Solution
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        HashMap<String, String> map = createMap();
        System.out.println(getCountTheSameFirstName(map, "test"));
        System.out.println(getCountTheSameLastName(map, "test"));
    }
    public static HashMap<String, String> createMap()
    {
        HashMap<String, String> odin = new HashMap<String, String>();
        odin.put("0","test");
        odin.put("1","test");
        odin.put("2","test");
        odin.put("3","test");
        odin.put("4","test");
        odin.put("5","test");
        odin.put("6","test");
        odin.put("7","test");
        odin.put("8","test");
        odin.put("9","test");

        return odin;
    }

    public static int getCountTheSameFirstName(HashMap<String, String> map, String name)
    {
        int count = 0;
        for(Map.Entry<String, String> lol : map.entrySet()){

            String value = lol.getValue();
            if(name.equals(value)){
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static int getCountTheSameLastName(HashMap<String, String> map, String familiy)
    {
        int count=0;
        for (Map.Entry<String,String> pair : map.entrySet())
        {
            String key = pair.getKey();
            if (familiy.equals(key))
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry Mijin!! I wanted to put a comment but in that time I'm not allow to add any comment :(

Comment: No problem. Predict_it is satisfied with your answer and in that case this is OK.

Answer (score 2):

Please consult the `HashMap`-API, it is correct by definition: "Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map. If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced." (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put(K, V))

Answer (score 1):

You are inserting the same key `10` times.  The first `put` works, but each subsequent `put` replaces the old key/value mapping with the same mapping.  The end result is that there's only one key/value pair in the `Map`, so that's why you get `1` as output.

Comment: i changed keys to 1 2 2 2 3 4 5 6 , i get as output 0 , 0

Answer (score 1):

**In short:** Your method works as HashMap is designed - you force put to HashMap with same key and first time add value to map, and any other time you just change value of this element because it has same key.

**Description:**

You have this situation - You are created HashMap like that:

```
HashMap<String, String> odin = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

There is first string key and second string value. When you adding value with line:

```
odin.put("test","test");
```

You are set value test for key test.

If you repeat that, you will change old element with key test with new element with key test

This results is that entered value is replaced.

Instead of this, you have to put in HashMap something else (array for example) with unique key. In this case you can have 10 inputs with same values.

Here is example of this HashMap:

```
HashMap<String, String[]> odin = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
```

In that case you have to provide string key and array of strings which contains values (first names and last names from your question).